# Prime numbers and arithmetic progressions

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Whether there exist a polynomial $f$ such that for every $n$ there exist prime numbers $p_1, \ldots, p_n$, and an integer $b$ such that every $p_i$ and $b$ are less than $f(n)$ and $p_1×\ldots×p_n×b + 1$ is prime?

Comment: Do you know the answer to this simpler question?: Is there a polynomial (or other nice bound) $g$ such that, given $k\in\mathbb{N}$, there is a prime $\leq g(k)$ congruent to $1\pmod{k}$?

Comment: @Slade yes, see: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/80865/least-prime-in-a-arithmetic-progression